# Swift protocol for shared functionality

Tags: swift, protocols

I have a number of objects, and each need to be locked until purchased.

Each of these objects (NSManaged) have a `productName String` and `isPurchased Bool`.

I wrote a function `isLocked()` which uses there properties as well an external check in a singleton.

How can this be combined into a protocol so that the protocol contains the isLocked function implementation and the objects can just adhere to the protocol and then call isLocked when needed?

Comment: If you need a common implementation, it sounds like you're looking for a superclass instead of a protocol.

Comment: Yes, obviously, but that will require extensive refactoring which isnt possible at this point. I was sure I saw something like this achieved using a protocol.

Comment: check at Protocol-Oriented Programming at Raywenderlich's site https://www.raywenderlich.com/109156/introducing-protocol-oriented-programming-in-swift-2 or in wwdc2015 https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/408/. Hope that it helps.

Answer (score 2):

If im not mistaken this can be achieved with Default implementations in swift.

```
protocol Locakable {
 var productName: String { get }
 var isPurchased: Bool { get }

 func lock()
 func unlock()
}

extension Locakable {

     func isLocked() {
        if isPurchased {
           //do something
           //lock it
           unlock()
         } else {
           lock()
         }
    }
 }
```

For more info on what mixin or default implementation is then chek out this wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin

However, note that `isLocked()` is dispatched statically. Comment if something is unclear.

You can also abstract the idea of locking and unlocking and write a default implementation on the protocol extension if possible. Or provide a customisation point like so.

```
class Item: Locakable {
var productName = "ItemName"
var isPurchased = false

init () {
    isLocked()
}

func lock() {

}

func unlock() {

}
}
```

Comment: For more information you can check Apple docs https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html Protocol Extensions section. Also probably NSHipster's manual will be more suitable for you http://nshipster.com/swift-default-protocol-implementations/.

Comment: the productName and isPurchased are attributes on each of the core data entities, I cannot declare them inside the protocol.

Comment: use a computed property which will encapsulate this properties.